# How to test for presence of "nohref" attribute in IE6/7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6, imagemap

The `nohref` attribute on an `area` tag causes the are to be specifically excluded from an image map. It works in IE 6-7 in that you can see the mouse pointer is not changed when hovering over an area marked as such. The rectangle has a "nohref" and the blue circle doesn't.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZNMEC/7/

However, I can't figure out any way to programatically test for it in Javascript that works in IE 6 & 7. `getAttribute` always returns `false` whether the attribute is present or not. jQuery `.attr` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [XHTML standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-xhtml2-20030131/mod-csImgMap.html), nohref attributes should be written as `nohref="nohref"`. If you do that, you can easily test for it as `.attr('nohref')` will return the string `"nohref"`.

However this attribute is **no longer supported in HTML5**. From the [W3C working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/area.html):

> The nohref attribute on the area element is obsolete. Omitting the href attribute is sufficient.

Therefore you can test for it by `if($('area').attr('href')){ /* href is set */ }`.

Comment: I'm hoping to make this work universally. I guess I may end up having to do this if there's just no workaround for this in IE6/7, though.

Comment: I think this is the right way to handle this, e.g. test for absence of `href`. Even under previous specs `nohref` shouldn't appear simultaneously with `href` so all I would be handling by looking for nohref is invalid markup anyway.

Answer (score 2):

To select the `area` elements with the `nohref` attribute you can use the attribute-equals notation:

```
$('area[nohref]');
```

To demonstrate this being used:

```
alert($('area[nohref]').length);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNMEC/8/).

Reference:

- [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals/).

Comment: @jamietre: have you checked to be sure that there's no JavaScript errors anywhere in your code (and, if there are any, could you edit the errors into your question)? I don't have IE to play with to test, but I can't see why this *wouldn't* work (other than IE's usual foibles and difficulties, of course).

Comment: Look at the fiddle - it really could not be simpler. IE6-7 getAttribute just doesn't seem to recognize nohref. Add any other random (invalid) attribute you like to the area element and try to select it, and it will work. jQuery uses this as well (and likewise, the selector doesn't work since sizzle does the selection for IE6-7 and is ending up using getAttribute)